# Fill internet form with eclipse sikuli selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium, sikuli

I try to automate simple process to fill an internet form. I use the Eclipse environment with Sikuli and Selenium for this purpose. I follow the following tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8y41vKeGM9U. It seems there is no error in the code but I have the following error on the console. would you teach me the reason please ?

Best regards,

```
    error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(2560,360)@S(1)   [1920,0     1280x720]
 but after move is L(2347,240)@S(1)[1920,0 1280x720]
 Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was    running:
  Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application.
 You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.
 [error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(542,775)@S(0)[0,0     1920x1080]
 but after move is L(1920,719)@S(1)[1920,0 1280x720]
 Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running:
 Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application.
 You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
  at FillForm.main(FillForm.java:26)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.google.common.base.Function
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 1 more
```

Comment: The error says `You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin`. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Sorry I begin. I looked on internet but did not managed to understand the explanation when i find it. Could you explain with simple words please, I am still learning. Thanks

Comment: Try to follow this tutorial: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/configure-eclipse-with-selenium-webdriver/ and especially pay attention on sestion: *Add External Jars to Java build path*

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your comments. Well I managed to open Chrome but it do not continue with the code. Then, If I open a new Chrome with the website called with the code manually  that it continued the script in the new window. So I feel like there is something missing between Chrome open and the remainder. Do you have an idea please?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new separate question while you include sufficient data to make it possible to understand where the issue is. Do not forget to include your code.